# which oleaut32.dll is loaded

Tags: windows, vb6

On Windows 7 64 bit I have a visual basic 6 standard exe (no activex exe) on the one hand.
On the other hand I have two oleaut32.dlls, one is in c:\windows\system32 and the other is in c:\windows\syswow64.
They have different sizes.
How can I say (maybe which registry key), what oleaut32.dll will be loaded for the vb6 exe?
Thanks a lot in advance
Wolfgang

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The files in c:\windows\syswow64 directory exists on 64-bit versions of Windows.  The contents of this directory are all the 32-bit DLLs that normaly ship with the 32-bit install of Windows. When you run a 32-bit process on 64-bit Windows, the system loads the 32-bit DLLs from the c:\windows\syswow64 directory.  Otherwise for native 64-bit processes, c:\windows\system32.  (Yes, it's confusing given the name of these directories.  The directory called "System32" has 64-bit DLLs.  The directory called SysWow64 is for 32-bit DLLs).

So in short, the system binaries (including oleaut32.dll) are loaded from  c:\windows\syswow64 is the one loaded for your legacy VB app (which is a 32-bit process).

More info here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WoW64

Comment: And what do I have to do, when I have better dll, but do not want to overwrite the syswow64 file?

Comment: What version could possibly be better than the one that shipped with the latest version of the operating system?  Typically, you don't try to overwrite system components. However, if you have some specific version of this DLL that was part of an old public resist (such was the case with Win9x updates), then you typically can just copy this DLL into the same directory as your EXE. Typically the loader will search the same directory as the EXE for DLLs prior to searching the windows folders.

Comment: Dumping DLLs next to the compiled EXE is a bad idea unless they are not ActiveX DLLs and not system DLLs.  To handle "local" DLLs correctly there was the old .local file mechanism, which has many warts, and the SxS manifest mechanism which is more robust.

Comment: @Bob77 - I agree. It doesn't make much sense how the OP has a version of oleaut32.dll that can be expected to replace in-box version on any version of Windows. I suspect that the OP just needs to drop his version of oleaut32.dll in favor of just letting the system version load and his app will work just fine.